# Solving a system of transcendental equations

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-value

I am trying to solve the following system of transcendental equations:

```
-3*y*(x + w*(x + (G/2)*(1 - Exp[-x])^2)) = 0
-y^2 - (1/6)*(x + 3*w*(x + (G/2)*(1 - Exp[-x])^2)) = 0
w = 2
G = -5.729
```

This system cannot be solved algebraically, so I am trying to use `NSolve`, for which I  read that I should use `Rationalize` first. Then, the code is the following:

```
w = 2; 
G = -5.729;
a = Rationalize[-3*y*(x + w*(x + (G/2)*(1 - Exp[-x])^2))]
b = Rationalize[-y^2 - (1/6)*(x + 3*w*(x + (G/2)*(1 - Exp[-x])^2))]

Solutions = NSolve[a == 0 && b == 0 && 0 < x < 10 && -10 < y < 10, {x, y}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 10]
```

But the output is just `{}`, giving me an empty list (no solutions?). This result is clearly wrong (note that the range of values 0 < x < 10 and -10 < y < 10 is just approximately the area where I am interested on for the solutions). So what am I doing wrong? any other method I should try? I just need the "x" and "y" values for which that system is zero. I have tried some stuff with `FindRoot`, but without any success.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you made a plot of `a` and `b`? Can you clearly see that there is a region where both are zero simultaneously?

Comment: Likely a bug in view of `{a, b} /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}` which results in `{0,0}` as well as `{-3*y*(x + 
     w*(x + (G/2)*(1 - Exp[-x])^2)), -y^2 - (1/6)*(x + 
      3*w*(x + (G/2)*(1 - Exp[-x])^2))} /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}`.

Comment: You have the function $f(x) = x + w(x + (G/2)(1 - e^{-x})^2)$ in your definition for $a$. If I'm not mistaken, the derivative of this function is strictly positive (correct me if I'm wrong here.)  Moreover, $f(0) = 0$;  and since the function is strictly increasing, this is the only value of $x$ for which $f = 0$.  Thus, the only solutions for $a = -3yf(x) = 0$ are $y = 0$ or $x = 0$.  You could then search for points for which $b = 0$ and $y = 0$ or $b = 0$ and $x= 0$.  I believe that for these parameters, the only solution is $x = y = 0$.

Comment: This unique real solution can be found numerically by `NMinimize[{a^2 + b^2, x >= 0 && x <= 10 && y >= -10 && y <= 10}, {x, 
  y}, WorkingPrecision -> 20, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]`.

Comment: It should be noticed that `Reduce[Expand[a] == 0 && Expand[b] == 0 && 
  0 < x < 10 && -10 < y < 10, {x, y}]` results in `False`.

Comment: The only solution over the reals is at the origin. Which is excluded by the constraint that `x>0`.

Comment: @DanielLIchtblau: Indeed, `Reduce[Expand[a] == 0 && Expand[b] == 0 && 
  0 <= x <= 10 && -10 < y < 10, {x, y}]` results in `x == 0 && y == 0` as well as `Solve` and `NSolve` (up to the notation).

Answer (score 1):

```
FindRoot[eqns, {{x, 1}, {y, 1}}]
```

> ```
> {x -> -7.2006*10^-17, y -> 1.16587*10^-8}
> ```